# Disable ActiveForm Clientside Validation on button other than submit Yii2

Tags: yii2, yii2-advanced-app, yii2-model, yii2-validation

1. I have an upload excel to DB form.
2. It has 1 **File** input and 2 buttons '**Upload**' and '**Delete All**'.

**Problem Scenario:**

I don't want client-side activeform validation on 'Delete All' as File is not required here.

**Code:**

```
<?php $form = ActiveForm::begin([ 'enableClientValidation' => false, 
            'options' =>['action' => Url::toRoute('/site/halltickets')
                        ,'method' => 'POST'
                        , 'enctype'=>'multipart/form-data']]); ?>

<?= $form->field($model, 'file')
    ->fileInput()->label("Upload Only Excel File [Allowed Formats: xlsx, xls]") ?>
<center>
    <?= Html::submitButton('Upload &raquo;', ['class' => 'btn btn-warning']) ?>
    <?= Html::a('Delete All &raquo;',
        Url::toRoute(['site/delete-halltickets']),
        ['class' => 'btn btn-danger',
            'data-confirm' => Yii::t('yii', 'Delete all Hall Ticket Allocations?'),
        ]);?>
</center>
<?php ActiveForm::end(); ?>
```

to understand better, below is the image.

[image]

Comment: I don't understand your interface. What does "delete all" button? What problem happens when you press this button?

Comment: Why not just move the button/link out of the surrounding form?

Comment: @IStranger: Delete All button submits the form and delete all related hall tickets.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is bad idea to place "Delete All" button on the upload form. Insert this button outside the form. It will more user-friendly.

Additionally you can remove "required" validator from model. Or define it only for the specific [scenarios](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-structure-models.html#scenarios).